# Swift 3: CNcontactpicker's phonenumber return 'not fetched' in device

Tags: ios, swift, cncontact, cncontactviewcontroller

our apps have a feature to get device contact, i have just used CNcontacpickerview it works when i run it on emulator, but when it run on device, the phonenumber return 'not fetched'. is it because my permission or what? the weird is it works on emulator

[image]

```
import UIKit
import ContactsUI
import MessageUI

class SharedAboutViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,CNContactPickerDelegate,MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableview.delegate = self;
        self.tableview.dataSource = self;
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    func messageComposeViewController(_ controller: MFMessageComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MessageComposeResult) {
        //... handle sms screen actions
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func contactPicker(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelect contacts: [CNContact]) {
        for contact in contacts {
            print(contact)
        }

        let when = DispatchTime.now() + 0.2 // change 2 to desired number of seconds
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when) {
            // Your code with delay
            if (MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText()) {
                let controller = MFMessageComposeViewController()
                controller.body = "Message Body"
                controller.recipients = ["hello"]
                controller.messageComposeDelegate = self
                self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let contactPicker = CNContactPickerViewController()
        contactPicker.delegate = self
        contactPicker.displayedPropertyKeys =
            [CNContactNicknameKey
                ,CNContactEmailAddressesKey]

        self.present(contactPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5;
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cells");
        cell?.textLabel?.text = "hello";
        return cell!;
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return self.view.frame.height*0.08;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

solved

i just added this code in my page to show permission popout

```
let addressBookStore = CNContactStore()

addressBookStore.requestAccess(for: CNEntityType.contacts) { (isGranted, error) in
    print(isGranted)
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: My experience: if you use `contactPicker.displayedPropertyKeys`, the parts of the text template of printing `CNContact` will read "not fetched. For example, if you added the key for phone to that array, re-running the code would replace the "phoneNumbers=(not fetched) display with some `CNPhoneNumber` values.

Comment: I have done less learning about the store, but I think it makes sense (you *do* want to display limited info, but after the contact is selected, you do want to pull the entire set, even data that wasn't necessarily displayed)